# Quero Aprender a programar

Tags: python

Estou querendo aprender a programar, o que recomendam que eu faço primeiro? Vi em vários sites sobre python, que é uma linguagem para se aprender primeiro, é bom? Qual devo partir após? Obg!

Comment: Aprenda lógica de programação, algoritmos depois monte o ambiente da linguagem e pratique bastante

Comment: Se você não souber nada ainda, creio que o code.org é uma boa opção.

Comment: Oi Pedro, bem-vindo ao site. Perguntas como esta não costumam ser aceitas aqui no site, pois tendem a gerar muitas respostas puramente opinativas. Sugiro que tente começar com o que estiver a mão, e a partir daí traga dúvidas mais específicas conforme forem aparecendo. Parece que você está interessado a começar com Python, então vai fundo. Este link pode ser um bom começo: http://wiki.python.org.br/AprendaProgramar

Comment: Como a encontrada abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Para entender logica, comece com uma linguagem "fácil", como PASCAL, C++ que são as utilizadas junto a logica de programação nas faculdades e cursos e depois parta para orientadas a objetos e afins.

Apostila http://pt.slideshare.net/jocelmarios/lgica-de-programao-pascal

Curso em video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xM56Mf6n3Ec

Comment: Trocando a sugestão de linguagem introdutória de C++ (orientada a objeto) para C (procedural), concordo. E pessoalmente prefiro essas linguagens em que você aprende o conceito de ponteiro do que começar com o garbage-collection do Python, por exemplo.

Comment: Então meu amigo, o C++ também pode ser procedural, tudo depende da forma que tratada.

Comment: Pode, mas se formos deixar de lado a orientação a objeto do C++, o que sobra é o C. E para alguém querendo aprender por conta própria é melhor recomendar exatamente o que ele precisa aprender.